# Is it possible to trigger 2 events at the same time, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to trigger 2 events at the same time by clicking the "Past Locations" link on the right side navigation to jump to the bottom page to the "Past Locations" section and route a default image map (Indianapolis map) at the same time.

Currently, it jumps to the bottom of the page just fine, but the image map disappears - just nothing showing up in the placeholder of the map.

HTML - the other two working links routes image maps

```
<li class="j_linkHover">
  <a href="#mapCO-asp" class="j_linkThumb">Aspen, CO</a>
  <p class="j_accordion-panel"><span class="j_dateLocation">Central Regions<br>May 29 - June 3</span></p>
</li>

<li class="j_linkHover">
  <a href="#mapOR" class="j_linkThumb">Salem, OR</a>
  <p class="j_accordion-panel"><span class="j_dateLocation">Oregon School for the Deaf,<br>Washington School for the Deaf, <br> Non-Profit Community Event<br>June 3 - 6</span></p>
</li>

<li  class="j_linkHover">
  <a href="javascript: document.body.scrollIntoView(false);" id="location-color" class="j_linkThumb  is-active">Past Locations</a> <--- jumps to the bottom, but cannot route image map at the same time
</li>
```

JavaScript - this routes image maps in the placeholder

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //Default Action
  $(".mapActive").css({'display':'none'});
  $("ul.j_linkLocation li#mapIN").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
  $(".mapActive#mapIN").show(); //Show first tab content

  //On Click Event
  $("ul.j_linkLocation li").click(function() {
    $("ul.j_linkLocation li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".mapActive").css({'display':'none'}); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn('fast'); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
  });

});
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reuse the same functionality define it in a function:

```
function routeImages (elem) {
  $("ul.j_linkLocation li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(elem).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".mapActive").css({'display':'none'}); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(elem).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn('fast'); //Fade in the active content
}
```

So now your old code becomes like this:

```
//On Click Event
  $("ul.j_linkLocation li").click(function() {
    routeImages($(this));
  });
```

Then add a click listener to for the list item:

```
$('#location-color').parent('li').on('click', function() {
  //the first event
  $('body').scrollIntoView(false);

  //call the function for routing images
  routeImages($('ul.j_linkLocation li:first'));
});
```

Comment: I think that has chances to *loop*... On `click` -> trigger `click` looks scary. -- As a click "forwarder"... This also is a bad suggestion.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette you are right, I missed this. a better way it to have those in a function and then call that function from multiple listeners. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Sam Battat - your first code didn't work, but the Click Listener code worked perfectly! The image map remained there when "Past Location" was clicked and it went to the bottom of the page. Ill accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes... With jQuery, which is a JavaScript library... You can attach multiple `event` to an element.

```
$([element selector]).on([events... space separated], [Delegated selector], function([arg]){
  //  Whatever to execute
});
```

More concrete example (usefull for the syntax):

```
$("#myDiv").on("click mouseenter mouseleave tap touchstart touchend", ".innerBox", function(event){
  //  Whatever to execute
});
```

Read about the jQuery [event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

And here is the most complete [event list](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/) I know.

Extra reading would be about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)...

Comment: It is not an exclusive of jQuery - simple Javascript with multple addEventListener can do that.

Comment: @Nillus: Sure... But it is easy with jQuery... Now, whatever is possible with jQuery also is with vanilla JS.